# Print won't work inside a fortran function

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I wrote a fortran function to call a blas level 3 function sgemm. I'm passing the matrices to be multiplied to this function and returning the result. The code works and the result is also correct. But there is a print statement inside which won't print anything. Why is that happening?

```
function matmul(A,B) result(C)
    real,dimension(:,:),allocatable::A
    real,dimension(:,:),allocatable::B
    real,dimension(:,:),allocatable::C

    integer::m,n,k

    m = size(A,1)
    n = size(A,2)
    k = size(B,2)

    print *,"INSIDE FN"

    call sgemm ('N','N',m,k,n,1.0,A,n,B,k,0.0,C,k)




end function matmul
```

Comment: Do you do anything like `print matmul(g,h)`?

Comment: Weloe. Please post your complete code, we need to know how you call this function and how you distinguish it from the intrisic one. Take the welcome [tour] and see [ask].

Comment: I'm now inclined to think (note Vladimir F's comment) that this function isn't being used: most `sgemm`s won't be allocating that result `c`.  So, to second the above, please do show a complete program.

Comment: In addition, an old version of gfortran might not support recursive I/O in case you use that, as it wasn't permitted until recent Fortran standards.  As mentioned several times above, you would need to show a full example and your compiler version.

Answer (score 0):

The function name you chose, **`MATMUL`**, is a fortran intrinsic function (see section [13.7.105](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf) of the fortran standard or [here](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/matmul)). The function you implemented tries to 'overload/shadow' this intrinsic with the same name. This is possible in Fortran, but you have to explicitly inform the compiler about it. When compiling the following code :

```
function matmul(A,B) result(C)
  real,dimension(:,:),allocatable::A,B,C
  print *,"matmul overloaded"
  C=A
end function matmul

program test
  real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: A,B,C
  allocate(A(1,1),B(1,1),C(1,1))
  C = matmul(A,B)
end program test
```

The program `test` has no knowledge about the existence and/or interface of your own `matmul` subroutine. Both the program `test` and the subroutine `matmul` live in two unconnected program units, and as a consequence, the compiler will assume that the intrinsic `MATMUL` function is to be called.

**`EXTERNAL` attribute:** (see [STDF2003::5.3.9](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf))

As the compiler has no mechanism to access the users `matmul` code from the program unit `test`, it's interface is *implicit*. If you want to specify that the name `matmul` is the one of an external or dummy procedure, we can use the `external` statement :

```
program test
  external :: matmul
  real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: A,B,C
  allocate(A(1,1),B(1,1),C(1,1))
  C = matmul(A,B)
end program test
```

**`INTERFACE` block :** (See [STDF2003::12.4](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf))

With the `external` attribute, you just specify that `matmul` is an external or dummy procedure. It does not specify the interface, which remains implicit. The interface, however, can be defined by means of an interface block as

```
program test
  real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: A,B,C
  allocate(A(1,1),B(1,1),C(1,1))

  interface
    function matmul(A,B) result(C)
      real,dimension(:,:),allocatable::A,B,C
    end function matmul
  end interface

  C = matmul(A,B)
end program test
```

The latter is automatically achieved when placing the function `matmul` in a module and using that module.

***note:** information loosely adopted from* [Modern Fortran Explained, *M. Metcalf, J. Reid and M. Cohen*, (Oxford, 2013)](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Modern+Fortran+Explained)

Comment: 'Overloading' does not require a module.

Comment: @francescalus, but the overloading/shadowing seems to fail if the function is not inside a module or interface block (See updated answer)

Comment: This `matmul` requires an explicit interface (because of the allocatable things), but an interface block will suffice.  For a procedure not requiring an explicit interface an external declaration suffices.  That isn't to say a module is a good idea (it is), it just isn't necessary.

Comment: @francescalus I have updated the answer as it was not clear and inaccurate as was made clear by your previous comment. Feel free to comment

Comment: The answer is quite likely correct but I don't believe it is worth your time to write such an answer under a question which is quite unclear, we don't have the full code and not only the OP did not bother to respond to comments, he did not bother even to come back...